# PHP date() and strtotime() return wrong months on cron

Tags: php, date, datetime, cron, strtotime

I am using the following to get last month, in different formats, to use them later on.

```
<?
date("m", strtotime("first day of -1 month"));
strtolower(date("M", strtotime("first day of -1 month")));
date("F", strtotime("first day of -1 month"));
?>
```

This is supposed to run on cron and print them out to an external file. When I run this manually, works as a charm, and it prints out the correct month (july). However, the cronjob prints out December? (script is running in August).

Edit: php version is 5.4

Comment: Could you check the year? Seems like something is wrong because you are so far off. You might get 1970-01-01 as date so -1 month would be december.

Comment: Yeap, year gives off 1969! Any idea what could cause that?

Comment: Maybe another PHP version is used on command line? One that doesn't recognize "first day of".

Comment: Yeap, tried adding phpversion(); to the echo, gave out 5.2.17 on the cron, and 5.4 on the website. Going to check back with the host! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is still not solved for me, but this may help someone else. Problem is that cron for some reason using 5.2.17, while the rest of the website is using 5.4 as set.

Thanks to Langdi for pointing out that this could be the reason. Host is still unable to locate the source of the problem, I'll update here as soon as I reach anything.

--- Update, maybe it helps anyone in the future:

Here's the reply from my host, I think it fixes up the problem:

> The cron jobs on your account all start with php (which runs the
>   default php in whatever environment that you use it)
>
> php /path/script.php
>
> The problem is that the php version is set by the htaccess (which is
>   not active in the cron environment) so you need to use a different
>   command to select php 5.4 there. The full path to the interpreter.
>
> /usr/php/54/usr/bin/php
>
> if you also need the php.ini in your account on the cron you would add
>   -c then the path to that php.ini
>
> -c /path/public_html/php.ini
>
> so the command to use in the cron is:
>
> /usr/php/54/usr/bin/php -c /path/public_html/php.ini
>   /path/public_html/script.php

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime for this:

```
<?php
$dt = new DateTime('first day of last month');
echo $dt->format('F');
?>
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CkKy4I)

Comment: Still gives dec'69. Error log now shows:  

[13-Aug-2013 09:39:04] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (first day of last month) at position 10 (o): The timezone could not be found in the database' in /public_html/connlist/month_count.php

Comment: Sounds like an old version of PHP is at play. Probably 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set time zone in php in php.ini

You can check about time zone in php documentation here [Time Zone in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)